# Doing something when a widget leaves the screen

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose, I have a StatefulWidget, which periodically requests data from a server and this updates its state.

I prepared a `Timer.periodic()` to make the data get loaded off the main loop.

Now, if the widget leaves the screen, the **Timer continues to call** its callback.

**What is the correct mount point to perform cleanup actions, when the widget get off the screen?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to overwrite deactivate() of the `State<StatefulWidgeet>`:

```
@override
void deactivate() {
  super.deactivate();
  ...
}
```

See [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/deactivate.html).